# Canvas subclass not receiving KeyEvents

Tags: java, swing, canvas, event-handling

I have a subclass of `JFrame`, which contains an instance of `DrawingCanvas` ( a subclass of `java.awt.Canvas`), I have a `KeyListener` implemented in `DrawingCanvas`, but it's not receiving any key events.

I have also made the canvas focusable using the `setFocusable()` method, but still I'm unable to receive key events.

**DrawingCanvas.java**

```
class DrawingCanvas extends Canvas implements TimePulseListener, KeyListener { 
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP:
                xFlag = false;
                yFlag = true;
                reverseY();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT:
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT:
                xFlag = true;
                yFlag = false;
                reverseX();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" * NOT an action key ");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You added the canvas as listener?

Comment: @Jägermeister oops! my bad. That's exactly what I missed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to change your code like below.

```
    public DrawingCanvas() {
        super();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN:
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP:
                xFlag = false;
                yFlag = true;
                reverseY();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT:
            case KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT:
                xFlag = true;
                yFlag = false;
                reverseX();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(" * NOT an action key " + e.getKeyChar());
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Jägermeister in the comments, I have indeed missed registering the `KeyListener` in the other class, adding that resolved my issue.

```
class DrawThreads extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    ...

    public DrawThreads(int width, int height) {
        ...

        drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas();
        drawingCanvas.addKeyListener(drawingCanvas); // register listener
        drawingCanvas.setFocusable(true);

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```